# How do I update Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages without errors in my MVC5 project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, libraries

Using `VS2013`, I'm unable to update `Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages` and continue getting the following error:

```
 Updating 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages 2.0.20710.0' to
 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages 3.1.1' failed. Unable to find a version of
 'microsoft-web-helpers' that is compatible with
 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages 3.1.1'.
```

I have tried un/installing WebApi 2, OData, etc... still see this.

Suggestions?

Comment: Does `Update All` helps somehow ?

Answer (score 2):

I was running into the same problem trying to apply updates to MVC 3 in VS 2012. I Followed #ELHaix suggestions which would get me past the original problem but would then result in another error when I would try to run the upgraded project.

```
 Attempt by security transparent method 
 'System.Web.Mvc.PreApplicationStartCode.Start()' to access security critical 
 method 'System.Web.WebPages.PreApplicationStartCode.Start()' failed.
```

In researching and trying to resolve this problem I found a NuGet package that would upgrade from V3 to V4 and take care of all the problems. The following command in the NuGet Package Manager Console took care of the upgrade for me.

`Install-Package UpgradeMvc3ToMvc4`

Here's where I found the reference to the package: [UpgradeMvc3ToMvc4 NuGetPackage](http://www.dotnetexpertguide.com/2011/12/upgrade-aspnet-mvc-3-project-to-mvc-4.html)

Answer (score 1):

In reviewing the [Microsoft's MVC upgrade steps](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2), through the package manager console, I manually uninstalled `Microsoft-Web-Helpers` (there seemed to be an issue in updating this, then `Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages`.  Manually installed the 3.1.1 version of Microsoft-Web-Helpers, then `Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages`... all good.